# Unable to get values from the input fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have my handlebars file as

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="login-form">
            <form class="form-horizontal well">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="register">Not a Member? Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my app.js as

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    /*Submit login form*/

    $("#login").on('click', function(){
        var user = $("form input[type=text]").val();
        var pass = $("form input[type=password]").val();

        var data = {
            username : user,
            password : pass
        };

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : '/api/login',
            data : data
        });
    });
})
```

I am unable to use the values inside of the data object but when i try to do a simple alert using the user and pass values it alerts correct values but when doing a ajax call nothing is getting passed neither the user nor the pass inside the data object

Comment: You need to parse object use `JSON2.stringify(data)`

Comment: Or  change dataType to json using `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @Omi still i am getting undefined when i try to use the values inside data while trying to do an api call

Comment: @MTK no luck with using dataType : "json"

Comment: did you getting values inside your data plz check with console

Comment: does not log anything at all

Comment: How do you know that the data is not recieved on the other end?

Comment: pretty sure it is your ajax is not working https://jsfiddle.net/aLrhgrjd/

Comment: add an ajax callback after data: data, success: function(data){console.log(data)}, error: function(e){console.log(e);}

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem :

```
 $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/api/login',
            data : JSON.stringify(data)
        });
```

Added `dataType:"json"` and `data:JSON.stringify(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Also you try this

```
  $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '/api/login',
        data : $('form').serialize(),
    });
```